# BabylonJs textblock disappeared after camera goes through the object

Tags: camera, mesh, babylonjs

Refer to the example below, if you press Up arrow key and let the camera go through the sphere and the plane and press Down arrow to go back, the text block disappeared.

Is this a bug in BabylonJs?  How to fix this issue?

http://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#XCPP9Y#160

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug. I'll fix it asap (probably this Monday:))

Comment: Thanks for the fixing.